# Serve --watch not working in jekyll

Tags: ruby, windows, jekyll

I'm having a problem with jekyll. I thought I'd finally try it out so I clean installed it with the needed gems for windows (running windows 7 64bit). I go ahead and use

```
jekyll new Test
```

then cd into the test dir and use

```
jekyll serve --watch
```

and it flags up this

```
Configuration file: C:/Users/Defa1t/Desktop/Test/_config.yml
            Source: C:/Users/Defa1t/Desktop/Test
       Destination: C:/Users/Defa1t/Desktop/Test/_site
      Generating...
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.9/lib/posix
/spawn.rb:164: warning: cannot close fd before spawn
'which' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
←[31m  Liquid Exception: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass in _posts/2014-1
1-01-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown←[0m
jekyll 2.4.0 | Error:  undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: Let me guess: Windows? I have similar problems. Seems to relate to the version of Python used for the highlighter. Didn't resolve it yet, though.

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found -- and I hope it works for you too -- is to use an older version of **Python** (yes, Python, not Ruby -- the problem is probably the highlighter).

- Install Python 2.7 in a directory called, say, `C:\Python27`
- Change your PATH environment variable to have `C:\Python27` and `C:\Python27\Scripts` as  first entries. I used Rapid Environment Editor for that. You can of course also write a simple batch file that adds it in front of the existing entries:

  ```
  SET PATH=C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;%PATH%
  ```
- See if it works. It works for me.